# Is there a way to obfuscate Wordpress file download URLs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Im using ACF to associate a custom file field to WooCommerce on my site. That field will receive the customers invoice PDF once the order is completed. My problem is the files have a sequence numbering, which is helpful to keep so I can quickly identify them in the admin interface, but I don't want my customers to able to guess the numbering and easily open other invoices.

Is there any way to add a small obfuscation so that the URLs don't show any sequence any obvious sequence pattern?

Comment: WooCommerce uses something to handle downloadable files. I would look at that and see if it could be adapted to your use.